# Assessing locations across England with at least four retail shops from four different retailers in GIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, analysis

### 1A: Problem

I have a dataset (point data) of 500 retail shops across England distributed in a seemingly un-random fashion (some retailers may only be found in cities or in specific regions). There are approximately 20 different retailers each with a different number of shops. For example see the written discription below and figure 1:

- Retailer 1 has 290 retail shops
- Retailer 2 has 60 retail shops etc...

*Fig 1: Distribution of retailers and the number of shops they own in England*
[image]

I represent a fictional analytics company who needs to persuade these retailers to provide us with some data (the details of which do not matter) so that we can then aggregate the data from different retailers to get some unique business insights across England. In return the retailers who agree to provide the data get to see the aggregated data, but it is **anonomised**.

In order to anonimise the data we want to use the **4x4 rule** (a common annonimising technique used for this kind of task), which simply states to access the aggragated data the **search area** should contain **at least 4 retail shops from 4 different retailers**.

The **search area** for our problem is simply a 5-mile ring (buffer) from any given postcode sector centroid (point data).

### 1B: Question

We (the analytics company) do not expect all retailers to agree to give us their data so need to assess what the best combination or rank is in order to hit the 4x4 rule in the most search areas whilst having a good coverage over England. We can then use this knowledge to prioritse our time and effort into which retailers we approach.

### 2: My thinking so far (I am a QGIS 3.16 user)...

1. I take a random sample of points across England (circa 5,000).
2. I create a 5-mile buffer on each of these random points.

**This is where I become a little stuck**

3. It seems to me like there are so many combinations of retails across England that this becomes a really difficult question to answer. I'm not looking for a solution good enough to be published I just wondered if there are any clever ways of solving this.
4. Ideally I'm looking for a solution I can implement in QGIS and/or Excel if needed.

Comment: So... you want to create `DB-scan clusters` of at least 4 points within 5 miles of each other?

Comment: Without sounding thick, I'm not sure if that is what I want to do. The criteria means the 4 points (retail shops) have to all be different retailers. Let me have a quick look at what the algorithm does...

Comment: @Erik hmm I'm not sure that does answer the question on it's own but appreciate I may not have explained the problem well enough.

Comment: That's not sounding thick, that's adding details =) so no worries. Also, I seldomly do work with huge amounts of data, hence the proposal in a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A) Creating a fixed number of buffers in areas where shops are closest (highest density areas)

1. The idea is: for each shop, find the 5 nearest neighbors and create lines to these five next shops. Calculate the line length and get the sum of these 5 line distances. Do this by creating a new attribut called `next5` with [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator) and this expression:

   ```
    array_sum (
        array_foreach (
            overlay_nearest (@layer, $geometry, limit:=5),
            length (make_line ($geometry, @element))
        )
    )
   ```

   *Be aware: `array_sum` was introduced in QGIS 3.18. For earlier versions (3.0+), you have to use a slightly more complex expression:*

   ```
   with_variable (
       'array',
       array_foreach (
           overlay_nearest (@layer, $geometry, limit:=5),
           length (make_line ($geometry, @element))
       ),
       array_get (@array,0) + array_get (@array,1) + array_get (@array,2) + array_get (@array,3) + array_get (@array,4)
   )
   ```
2. Identify the 500 (or any other number you define in the last line) shops with the 5 nearest neighbors at smallest accumulated distances. Use this expression (with [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbyexpression) or [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator)). Be aware, array count starts at 0, so I have `499` to get the first 500 features:

   ```
    aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'array_agg', 
        next5, 
        order_by:=next5
    )[499] >= next5
   ```

*Result: dark blue dots represent the 500 points with closest distance to 5 neighbors out of 13.000 points all over England. A dissolved buffer of 5 km around these 500 points returns the light blue/red outlined buffer polygons: these are the areas with the densest concentration of shops all over England - as several neighboring buffers are dissolved, there are 151 buffers left from the initial 500 buffered points - you could, of course, stick to undissolved buffers to proceed:*

[image]

### B) Identify buffer polygons containing shops from 4 different companies

On your buffer layer, use select by expression with one of these expressions:

```
overlay_contains ('stores', filter:=company=1) and
overlay_contains ('stores', filter:=company=2) and
overlay_contains ('stores', filter:=company=3) and
overlay_contains ('stores', filter:=company=4)
```

or:

```
not array_contains (
    array_foreach (
        array (1,2,3,4),
        array_contains( 
           overlay_contains ('stores', company),
           @element
    )),
    false
)
```

- replace `stores` with the name of the layer that contains your retail shops.
- replace `company` with the fieldname that contains the name of the company each shop belongs to.
- in expression 2, replace 1,2,3,4 by a comma separated list of the four company names.

As you can see on the screenshot, the expression selects only those buffers that contains shops from all four companies. The same expression (returning true/false) could be used to create a new attribute using [Field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator).

[image]

*Highlighted in yellow: buffers with stores from all 4 different companies, created with the second expression:*

[image]

*In this fictional/randomized dataset, these are the 100 remaining buffer polygons which contain shops from at least four different companies:*

[image]

Comment: The array_sum function appears to be missing for me in QGIS 3.16 which is rather annoying

Comment: Indeed: this was introduces in QGIS 3.18. Updating to 3.22 (the next LTR) would be a good idea.

Comment: Updated answer to include a version for QGIS 3.16 as well